# How to get all variables from an array and echo it as a $_SESSION?

Tags: php, arrays, session, transfer, var-dump

**Page 1:**
On the page 1 I have a **for loop**:, which contains something like this:

```
$_SESSION['img_name'] = $img_name[$i];
```

When I call var_dump

```
var_dump($_SESSION['img_name']);
```

I get that there are 2 strings:

> string(6) "a2.JPG" string(6) "a3.JPG"

So I normally make the link to page 2 and instead of using `$_SESSION` I use just `$_GET` like this:

```
echo '<a href="page2.php?img='.urlencode($img_name[$i]).'">.'.htmlspecialchars($img_name[$i], ENT_QUOTES).'</a>'.'</br>';
```

But today I do not want to do that that way, I want to store `$img_name[$i]` in a `$_SESSION` and get those two variables from a `$_SESSION` **on page 2**.

**Page 2:**

```
echo $_SESSION['img_name'];
```

But the problem is that when I echo a `$_SESSION` on **page 2**, it contains only the last variable from an ***array***, it doesn't echo all.
How to get all variables being stored in an ***array***?

On **page 2** var_dump shows:

> string(6) "a3.JPG"

String

> string(6) "a2.JPG"

is missed. :(

**QUESTION 2:**

> Could You tell me how can I fetch the data outside the loop? Something
>   like: "echo $_SESSION['img_name'];" but outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the values for session each time in forloop

```
$_SESSION['img_name'] = $img_name[$i];
```

So change it to

```
$_SESSION['img_name'][] = $img_name[$i];
```

And in first page i think `var_dump()` in present inside for loop. So its coming correctly.

Comment: Hey, friend, I tried that already and I was getting an error: "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\wyslano.php on line 102"

Comment: try like this, `[$i]`

Comment: anso, `$_SESSION['img_name'] = array();` declre it outside the loop.

Comment: Lol, var_dump instead of showing a2, a3 on page 2, now shows aa. Still doesn't work. Ok, I am going to declare, wait  a second.

Comment: Now works, thanks! I am really happy! Took me 7 hours today to solve that!

Comment: Glad i could help you:)

Comment: Hey, there. Could You tell me how can I fetch the data outside the loop? Something like: "echo $_SESSION['img_name'];" but outside the loop.

Comment: You have to access through index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['img_name'][$i] = $img_name[$i]`

is what you're looking for.